# How to create multiple column fillable fields in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, foxit-reader

Is there a way to make a fillable field with 2 columns? I guess they are called 'interactive forms'. I have a list of items i want to fill 2 columns on a page in my PDF. I just need to make it fillable via FoxIt PhantomPDF. Example:

```
Person List:
A                               D
B                               E
C                               F
```

I also would like to know if there is a way to make a fillable field span two lines. Example:

```
Other:__________________________________________________________________________
________________________________________________________________________________
```

How do i make a field fill the area of the underlines above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no (reasonably easy) way to create two columns in a single multiline text field. So, for the person list, you might do better by providing 6 individual fields (as per example), or, if you want to have multiple entries in the same field, two multiline text fields.

For the Other question, there is the limitation of text fields that they are rectangles. You would have three possibilities:

a) Create two fields with an automatic overflow from field 1 to field 2 (which would require some logic)

b) Take the Other as a label left of, or above the field, and have a single multiline field; note that writing lines are essentially useless when you fill out a form on screen.

c) Make the "Other: " string part of the field value, and use some logic to enter it when needed, for example, use a little script in the Format event which adds "Other: " to the event.value. The field's value would be the text, the "Other: " would appear when you leave the field.

There is, however, a big issue. As far as I am informed (in form of an answer by Foxit customer support), they do not support JavaScript, which means that any solution using logic would not work.

Comment: thanks.  i didn't think i was gonna get the answer i wanted for the multiple columns.  BTW, FoxIt does support JavaScript, i've written several things for this PDF already.